# Is there any possible way to open different home page depending on which user is logged in Flutter?

Tags: json, flutter, dart

I'm currently developing an App in Flutter and I came across one problem which I'm trying to solve for a while without any success. After someone downloads the app he/she will have to register first in order to use it. User can choose between Driver or Promoter and depending on that, the user will fill up different registration forms. After that process is done (all the data is stored in RealTime database in 2 different folders, driverdata or promoterdata), User will be redirected to the Welcome Page (Authentication Page). After User types in their e-mail and password and click on Log In button, I want to program the path for users to open different Pages (DriverFeed or PromoterFeed).

I had an idea to write a function that will check if an id from user is stored in driverdata or promoterdata, but without any success. 
Then I was searching some other solutions on the internet and I came across this: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=3hj_r_N0qMs but I don't think that this is the good way to solve my problem. I don't want that any User has Moderator claims.

Comment: Perhaps you can look at this question:https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57235319/flutter-sharedpreferences-not-fetching-value-at-app-start/57236248#57236248. The original poster was using shared preferences, you can do the same with data from the database

Comment: Don't you have `role` field in your db?

Comment: @MuhammadNoman No I don't have it. I can add that field in my db easily, but I dont know what can I do with it. Do you think I should add that field and then make a function that will check only that field in my db?

Comment: @WillieNandi Thanks for the link, I am trying now to Use Shared Preferences. I'll post an update if I have any success with it.

Comment: @kmtz, you can put roles in that role field, and after successfully logged in, based on that, you can redirect on different pages, depending on what role value is coming of that record

Answer (score 0):

Here is the solution that is working at the moment but not the way I wanted to. I am using ScopedModels and In my connected class / UserModel I wrote:

```dart
    Future<String> getUserStatus() async {
    SharedPreferences prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
    String userStatus = prefs.getString('userStatus');
    return userStatus;
  }

  Future<bool> setUserStatus(String userStatus) async {
    SharedPreferences prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
    prefs.setString('userStatus', userStatus);
    return true;
  }
```

Then in the registration Page after the user enters all his data and click on submit button, depending on which user is registering I set their value to the 'driver' or 'promoter' with the following funciton:

```dart
   setUserStatus('driver'); 
or
   setUserStatus('promoter');
```

Then in my AuthPage where the user is Loging in, when the user enter his e-mail and password and click on the LogIn button I'm calling log in Function and it looks like this:

```dart
 Future<void> _submitForm(Function login) async {
    if (!_formKey.currentState.validate()) {
      return;
    }
    _formKey.currentState.save();
    final Map<String, dynamic> successInformation =
        await login(_formData['email'], _formData['password']);

    if (successInformation['success']) {
      model.getUserStatus().then((a) {
        if (a == 'driver') {
          Navigator.of(context).pushReplacementNamed('/driverfeed');
        } else if (a == 'promoter') {
          Navigator.of(context).pushReplacementNamed('/promotions');
        } else {
          return Container();
        }
      });
    } else {
      showDialog(
          context: context,
          builder: (BuildContext context) {
            return AlertDialog(
              title: Text('An Error Ocurred'),
              content: Text(successInformation['message']), 
              actions: <Widget>[
                FlatButton(
                  child: Text('Okay'),
                  onPressed: () {
                    Navigator.of(context).pop();
                  },
                )
              ],
            );
          });
    }
  }
```